# Use of which and %in% when no items of a vector match

Tags: r

Let's say I have three vectors, and I want to compare them to see elements of each are NOT in the others, starting by comparing to "c."

```
a<-c(1,2,7,8)
b<-c(1,2,3,4)
c<-c(3,4,5,6)
```

So this works like I expect it to (1 and 2 are in "b" but not "c.")

```
b[-which(b%in%c)]
```

returns:

```
[1] 1 2
```

But this doesn't tell me which of "a" is not in "c" (all of it, i.e. 1,2,7,8), rather it gives me a numeric vector with nothing in it.

```
a[-which(a%in%c)]
```

returns:

```
integer(0)
```

It looks like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211077/match-a-vector-to-a-list-of-vectors) would do what I want in the end, but what am I misunderstanding about how my use of `which` and `%in%` works? Better yet, how do I get the answer

```
[1] 1 2 7 8
```

from the question of which of "a" is not in "c" when none of "a" is in "c?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using logical operations is more reliable:

```
b[!b %in% c]
# [1] 1 2
a[!a %in% c]
# [1] 1 2 7 8
```

Note that `!a %in% c` is the same as `!(a %in% c)`. In this way we ask which of `a` are in `c`, get a logical result, and negate it. Using `which`, on the other hand, works differently: in `-which(a %in% c)` we also first get a logical vector `a %in% c` and then `which` gives the *indices* of elements of `a` that belong to `c`, and get's rid of those elements. In your case we have

```
which(a %in% c)
# integer(0)
```

Then you may argue that `a[-numeric(0)]` should also return

```
# [1] 1 2 7 8
```

but that's not how it is in R.

Answer (score 3):

In case of `unique` elements, `setdiff` can be an alternative

```
setdiff(a, c)
#[1] 1 2 7 8

setdiff(b, c)
#[1] 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option. You can use `match` and then subset `NA` values (i.e. values which are not in both vectors). Try out

```
b[is.na(match(b, c))]
#[1] 1 2

a[is.na(match(a, c))]
#[1] 1 2 7 8
```